# Relation of stdin and EOF in C

Tags: c, printf, stdin, fopen, eof

A C quiz had these four questions that deal with fprintf and EOF. They weren't really explained in the section of the course related to these questions and I can't find good answers for them online.

Is the reason for the numbers printed on the screen and/or compilation fail the result of fprintf or its relation to EOF?

> ```
> #include <stdio.h> 
>
> int main(void) { 
>     int i; 
>     i = fprintf(stdin,"Hello!"); 
>     printf("%d",i == EOF); 
>     return 0; 
> }
> ```
>
> Answer: the program outputs 1
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h> 
>
> int main(void) { 
>     int i; 
>     i = fprintf(stderr,"Hello!"); 
>     printf("%d",i == EOF); 
>     return 0; 
> }
> ```
>
> Answer: the program outputs 0 to the stdout stream
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h> 
>
> int main(void) { 
>     FILE *f; 
>     int i = fprintf(f,"Hello!"); 
>     printf("%d",i == EOF); 
>     return 0; 
> }
> ```
>
> Answer: the compilation or execution fails
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h> 
>
> int main(void) { 
>     FILE *f = fopen("file","w"); 
>     int i = fprintf(f,"Hello!"); 
>     printf("%d",i != EOF); 
>     return 0; 
> }
> ```
>
> Answer: the program outputs 1

Comment: None of these results are specified by the language. `EOF` is only required to be a negative value, but it can be any negative number. Similarly, `fprintf()` returns a negative number when it gets an error, but it can also be any negative number. There's no requirement that these negative numbers be the same.

Comment: The third one causes undefined behavior. You never initialized `f`, so you can't use it as an argument to `fprintf()`.

Comment: @Barmar I see. why is i = fprintf(stdin,"Hello!"); returning a negative?

Comment: `stdin` is only open for reading, you can't write to it, so it gets an error.

Comment: @Barmar Oh I got it . thanks

Comment: @Onederfoo "stdin is only open for reading" which, while true most of the time, is not necessarily the case.

Comment: The C standard is indeed confusing. **`fscanf` will return `EOF` on error** but the magnitude of the return value from `fprintf` upon error is not specified!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOF is a macro that is very commonly equal to -1.

1. **Q1 :**

   - `stdin` is an input stream. Therefore using fprintf on it created a conflict, which apparently was handled by `fprintf()` and returned -1. ( as mentioned in the comments the return values in case of an error can be any negative number ).
   - In this sense the condition `(i == EOF)` returned true which is 1. which explains the answer.
2. **Q2 :**

   - `stderr` is an output stream, meaning printing into it was a success
   - `i = ...`, `i` contains the number of characters written. >0
   - `i == EOF` evaluates to 0.
   - 0 got printed
3. **Q3 :**

   - `fprintf` tries to print into a stream with the address `f`
   - `f` is a pointer with a garbage value, which means it might be pointing to a memory owned by the OS.
   - A write to that address resulted in a compilation or execution fails
4. **Q4 :**

   - `fprintf` does its job and write 5 chars into the file `f`
   - `i` gets initialized with the value 5
   - `i != EOF` evaluates to `5 != -1`, which is true, the is stored as the number 1 in memory
   - printed value is 1

Comment: that's great information and fully answers my question. Thank you